# Should I use MongoDB sparse index for optional sub-documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have a 'post' collection with different kinds of posts. In my use case, I have a property 'listings' post document which is stored as an embedded document inside it.

```
listings:{price:0,rooms:0,size:0....}
```

I created an index on the sub document and I ensure the query follows the field order.

My question is, can I create a sparse index for the entire `listings` sub document because it seems to be a waste to include the embed in every document in the post collection, just so I can index it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a sparse index on any field, including one that contains a JSON document.

However, even if you use a regular index you do not need to create the embedded "listings" field in every document - having a regular index on a field does *not* imply the field needs to exist in every document.